# Not able to get Route parameter - Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have tried multiple solution but nothing worked yet, i am trying to get route Parameter in controller that was passed from a view.
Here is how i have created the route:

```
Route::get('addOptions/{questionId}', 'QuestionController@addOptions')->name('addOptions');
```

Here is how i am passing parameter to route from view:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.addOptions', $data['question']->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Add Options</a>
```

And here is what i am trying to get in controller but it's returning empty array:

```
public function addOptions(Request $request)
{
   $allParameters = $request->input(); //not working
    //$allParameters = $request->all(); //not working
    //$allParameters = Input::all();    //not working

    return $allParameters;
}
```

It returns empty array `[]` like this.
EDIT: But url at route `addOptions` look like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/addOptions/4` in which `4` is questionId which means parameter is being passed but not retrieved.
What am I doing wrong here? Please guide, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the route like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.addOptions', ['questionId' => $data['question']->id]) }}" class="btn btn-success">Add Options</a>
```

as for [Laravel docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing) the route params are passed an array with the key referencing the param

```
$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

To retrieve the data in your controller, you should use:

```
   $request->route()->paremeters()
```

or

```
 $request->route('parameter_name')
```

Comment: Your way didn't work either. I have updated the question please check at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the parameter

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.addOptions', $question->id }}" class="btn btn-success">Add Options</a>
```

Comment: I have updated the question please check at the end

Answer (score 0):

I think your function parameters are wrong
You are passing question id from Route So your function should be like

```
public function addOptions($questionId)
{
  $allParameters = $questionId; // you question ID passed throught Route
  return $allParameters;
}
```